# Are there any free OpenCV classifier libraries?

Tags: opencv

Been tinkering with OpenCV in python. The face detection demo is impressive.

Are there any free collection of Haar classifiers aside from the face, eyes and full body ones?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, there are a few common ones which show up in most people's projects, although opencv should come with these:

1. [cv haar cascades](http://sysinf0.klabs.be/usr/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_upperbody.xml?dist=;arch=)
2. [eye cascades](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~shameem/haarcascade_eye.html)

You can make your own cascades, but be warned, it's a pretty cumbersome process. The best tutorial I found was [this one](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html).

HTH

Comment: Yep I've played around with the ones that come with openCV and those are interesting.  I've also read through articles on the process of creating your own and that was rather demoralizing - maybe a project for me to spend a few years on after I retire as it seems to take a long time to do.  What I'm hoping for is a set of classifiers that people around the world have already produced for all sorts of objects for example: building, ball, grass, sky, tree, forest, road etc.

Comment: @Khorkrak I know what you mean about haar training. I used OpenCV with Processing, and wrote a simple app that downloads images from flickr, than had to do cropping by hand :( As far as I know there is no haar database, but that would be so useful.

Comment: I followed this guide here: http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html, which was really good. The process can take a while, but it's not to terrible.

Answer (score 2):

Alejandro F. Reimondo has a few cascades on his site: http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34